# Can't we use this code to display image in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, image, model-view-controller

I am using this code to display image in my Gallery View but unfortunately i its shows blank infact it does not show any kind of error.

```
<a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/b.jpg")" alt=""></a>
```

The Code which i am using in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your project called "images", then put the picture you want to display on it and add an existing item to the folder on vs selecting your image.

On the view just use this:

```
<img src="~/images/yourimagename.jpg or png" alt"">
```